# Read and write bytes from a file (c++)

Tags: c++, file-io

I think I probably have to use an fstream object but i'm not sure how. Essentially I want to read in a file into a byte buffer, modify it, then rewrite these bytes to a file. So I just need to know how to do byte i/o.

Comment: You want to open it in binary mode.

Comment: @GManNickG This cannot be stressed enough. Failure to do so will cause you to smash your head against the wall for an hour or so with random bugs.
For example... code works if you insert a random `cout << file_stream.tellg();` somewhere and fails otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>

ifstream fileBuffer("input file path", ios::in|ios::binary);
ofstream outputBuffer("output file path", ios::out|ios::binary);
char input[1024];
char output[1024];

if (fileBuffer.is_open())
{
    fileBuffer.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    fileBuffer.getline(input, 1024);
}

// Modify output here.

outputBuffer.write(output, sizeof(output));

outputBuffer.close();
fileBuffer.close();
```

From memory I think this is how it goes.

Comment: i would usually make them dynamic because i wouldn't put them all in one function likfe

Comment: You still need to delete m_content after using new. C++ doesn't have garbage collection.

Also 1024 bytes should fit on the stack quite easily so just use `char m_content[1024];`

Comment: There's also no reason to declare and construct outputBufferHere so early.

Comment: Also, outputbuffer should be type `ofstream` not `ifstream`.

Comment: And this only works for files that are at most 1K.  Anything larger and the data will be truncated.

Comment: @potatoswatter, yeah sorry didn't get much time to write it, was at work tryggn to hammer it out.
@Freund, your just being pedantic, it is better to declare it at the beginning of the function i.m.o, because it looks messy declaring it half way through.
@Klatchko, once again it is an example, i'm not doing his work for him. I'm sure the guy is clever enough to realise is it 1024 bytes reading in only

Comment: Pretty sure this should be changed to `fileBuffer.read(input, 1024);`. In my case, I was reading a text file with carriage returns and line feeds, but I wanted it to be treated like a binary file, and `getline` was refusing to read past the line feed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with a small file size, I recommend that reading the whole file is easier. Then work with the buffer and write the whole block out again. These show you how to read the block - assuming you fill in the open input/output file from above reply

```
  // open the file stream
  .....
  // use seek to find the length, the you can create a buffer of that size
  input.seekg (0, ios::end);   
  int length = input.tellg();  
  input.seekg (0, ios::beg);
  buffer = new char [length];
  input.read (buffer,length);

  // do something with the buffer here
  ............
  // write it back out, assuming you now have allocated a new buffer
  output.write(newBuffer, sizeof(newBuffer));
  delete buffer;
  delete newBuffer;
  // close the file
  ..........
```

Comment: Or should could just alter buffer and write it back out.

Comment: All depend on the modification type. Would be easier if it is just one to one replacement of one or more bytes in the stream. However, if the alteration add more bytes to it, it can cause memory overflow exception - which is a common pitfall.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

const static int BUF_SIZE = 4096;

using std::ios_base;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   std::ifstream in(argv[1],
      ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);  // Use binary mode so we can
   std::ofstream out(argv[2],            // handle all kinds of file
      ios_base::out | ios_base::binary); // content.

   // Make sure the streams opened okay...

   char buf[BUF_SIZE];

   do {
      in.read(&buf[0], BUF_SIZE);      // Read at most n bytes into
      out.write(&buf[0], in.gcount()); // buf, then write the buf to
   } while (in.gcount() > 0);          // the output.

   // Check streams for problems...

   in.close();
   out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While doing file I/O, you will have to read the file in a loop checking for end of file and error conditions.  You can use the above code like this

```
while (fileBufferHere.good()) {  
    filebufferHere.getline(m_content, 1024)  
    /* Do your work */  
}
```